# Converting a WPFToolkit DataGrid from 1D list to 2D matrix

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpftoolkit

I am wondering if anyone has attempted the following or has an idea as to how to do it.

I have a WPFToolkit DataGrid which is bound to an ObservableCollection of items.  As such, the DataGrid is shown with as many ***rows*** in the ObservableCollection, and as many columns as I have defined in for the DataGrid.  That all is good.  What I now need is to provide another view of the same data, only, instead, the DataGrid is shown with as many ***cells*** in the ObservableCollection.

So let's say, my ObservableCollection has 100 items in it.  The original scenario showed the DataGrid with 100 rows and 1 column.  In the modified scenario, I need to show it with 10 rows and 10 columns, where each cell shows the value that was in the original representation.  In other words, I need to transform my 1D ObservableCollection to a 2D ObservableCollection and display it in the DataGrid.  I know how to do that programmatically in the code behind, but can it be done in XAML?

Let me simplify the problem a little, in case anybody can have a crack at this.  The XAML below does the following:

```
* Defines an XmlDataProvider just for dummy data
* Creates a DataGrid with 10 columns
      o each column is a DataGridTemplateColumn using the same CellTemplate
* The CellTemplate is a simple TextBlock bound to an XML element
```

If you run the XAML below, you will find that the DataGrid ends up with 5 rows, one for each book, and 10 columns that have identical content (all showing the book titles).  However, what I am trying to accomplish, albeit with a different data set, is that in this case, I would end up with one row, with each book title appearing in a single cell in row 1, occupying cells 0-4, and nothing in cells 5-9.  Then, if I added more data and had 12 books in my XML data source, I would get row 1 completely filled (cells covering the first 10 titles) and row 2 would get the first 2 cells filled.

Can my scenario be accomplished primarily in XAML, or should I resign myself to working in the code behind?

Any guidance would greatly be appreciated.  Thanks so much!

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Name="UserControl"
d:DesignWidth="600" d:DesignHeight="400"  >
<UserControl.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="InventoryData" XPath="Inventory/Books">
        <x:XData>
            <Inventory xmlns="">
                <Books>
                    <Book ISBN="0-7356-0562-9" Stock="in" Number="9">
                        <Title>XML in Action</Title>
                        <Summary>XML Web Technology</Summary>
                    </Book>
                    <Book ISBN="0-7356-1370-2" Stock="in" Number="8">
                        <Title>Programming Microsoft Windows With C#</Title>
                        <Summary>C# Programming using the .NET Framework</Summary>
                    </Book>
                    <Book ISBN="0-7356-1288-9" Stock="out" Number="7">
                        <Title>Inside C#</Title>
                        <Summary>C# Language Programming</Summary>
                    </Book>
                    <Book ISBN="0-7356-1377-X" Stock="in" Number="5">
                        <Title>Introducing Microsoft .NET</Title>
                        <Summary>Overview of .NET Technology</Summary>
                    </Book>
                    <Book ISBN="0-7356-1448-2" Stock="out" Number="4">
                        <Title>Microsoft C# Language Specifications</Title>
                        <Summary>The C# language definition</Summary>
                    </Book>
                </Books>
                <CDs>
                    <CD Stock="in" Number="3">
                        <Title>Classical Collection</Title>
                        <Summary>Classical Music</Summary>
                    </CD>
                    <CD Stock="out" Number="9">
                        <Title>Jazz Collection</Title>
                        <Summary>Jazz Music</Summary>
                    </CD>
                </CDs>
            </Inventory>
        </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="GridCellTemplate">
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <Binding XPath="Title"/>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>

</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <custom:DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
    Background="{DynamicResource WindowBackgroundBrush}" HeadersVisibility="All" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed"
    SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader" CanUserResizeRows="False" GridLinesVisibility="None" RowHeaderWidth="35" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False">
        <custom:DataGrid.Columns>
            <custom:DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource GridCellTemplate}" Header="01" />
            <custom:DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource GridCellTemplate}" Header="02" />
            <custom:DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource GridCellTemplate}" Header="03" />
            <custom:DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource GridCellTemplate}" Header="04" />
            <custom:DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource GridCellTemplate}" Header="05" />
            <custom:DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource GridCellTemplate}" Header="06" />
            <custom:DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource GridCellTemplate}" Header="07" />
            <custom:DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource GridCellTemplate}" Header="08" />
            <custom:DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource GridCellTemplate}" Header="09" />
            <custom:DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource GridCellTemplate}" Header="10" />
        </custom:DataGrid.Columns>
        <custom:DataGrid.ItemsSource>
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource InventoryData}" XPath="Book"/>
        </custom:DataGrid.ItemsSource>
    </custom:DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

So, to rephrase your question simply, you have a collection of objects and you want to display them horizontally with 10 to a row. If there are more than 10, the extra items wrap around (reflow) to the next row.

**Here's how you can do it extremely easily:**

*Don't use DataGrid.* That's basically only for displaying objects 1 object to a row where columns show various pieces of data for that object.

Instead, use ListBox or ListView, and give it a new `ItemsPanel`, like so (use data templates to display complex objects):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollectionOfObjects}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="10"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

This will replace the default `VirtualizingStackPanel` used by ListBox to arrange its items with `UniformGrid`. The reason for using UniformGrid is because you can specify the number of Columns and/or Rows the grid should have. The panel will equally divide the display area among the ListBox's items, but with 10 columns (as you want).

If you don't want a fixed number of columns/rows, you could instead use a `WrapPanel` which would fit as many objects into a single row as possible and wrap to the next row, a bit like `inline-block` elements in html, or left-justified text.

One last thing: remember that each of these 3 panels I just mentioned can have their `Orientation` set to either `Horizontal` (default for UniformGrid and WrapPanel) or `Vertical` (default for VirtualizingStackPanel and StackPanel).

Furthermore, you could write your own panels for custom item layout (e.g. arranging items in a circle).